# Views exists in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-query

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL view in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507995/sql-view-in-mongodb)

I am newbie to mongodb (java).

I need to know whether something like views(in relational) exists in mongodb?

Is it possible to create views mongodb?

Comment: An update: Views exist since version 3.4: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

...unless you count queries as views.

Comment: Totally true back in '12. No longer true as of version 3.4.